# .htaccess mod_rewrite url with multiple optional parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm pretty new to this mod_rewrite business but I'd like to have a rule that allows me to accomplish the following:

```
localhost/module_name/ -> localhost/index.php?module=module_name
localhost/module_name/module_action -> localhost/index.php?module=module_name&action=module_action
localhost/module_name/module_action/parm1 -> localhost/index.php?module=module_name&action=module_action&parm_1=parm1
localhost/module_name/module_action/parm1/parm2 -> localhost/index.php?module=module_name&action=module_action&parm_1=parm1&parm_2=parm2
```

and so on. I managed to get module_name and module_action to work, but I can't figure out how get it to work with only a module or with multiple parameters. This is what I currently have:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+) index.php?module=$1&action=$2
RewriteRule ([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?module=$1&action=$2&parm=$3
```

The first rule seems to work but it breaks apart on the second one.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may try this:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*    index.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4  [L]
```

Maps silently

`http://localhost/val1/` up to

`http://localhost/val1/val2/val3/val4`

To:

`http://localhost/index.php?key1=val1` up to

`http://localhost/index.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4`

Not incoming `valN` values are empty in the substitution URL.

`index.php` is considered a fixed string.

For permanent redirection, replace [L] with `[R=301,L]`,

Maximum number of parameters = 4.

Comment: This seems to work, but I currently have my site in a subdirectory and it takes the name of the directory as the first parameter. I tried changing the rewritebase but can't get it to work. Ideally it would work the same in my dev environment where the site resides in a sub directory as in the production environment where the site resides in the root.

Comment: Ok, I think i got to work. Changed the condition to: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/[^/]+/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC] for my dev environment. I'll just change it back once I move to production.

Comment: @Splatbang Okay. I was just leaving a comment to suggest the modifications. Glad you made it work.