# URL Rewriting – First value doesn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create friendly URLs using:

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Everything works normally when I try:**

www.mydomain.com/en/my-page/

OR

www.mydomain.com/en/my-page/my-subpage/

**However, I get 404 error when I try this:**

www.mydomain.com/en/

I've been trying understand the problem.
Thanks in advance.

## –Edit–

Anubhava's solution works very well. In addition to that, [here is another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14622381/3195189) if you need optional parameters.

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?   [NC]
    RewriteRule .*    index.php?lang=%1&page=%2&subpage=%3&anotherkey=%4  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
Options +Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options -MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2&subpage=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```